# Using South migrations with IBM Bluemix

Tags: django, database-migration, django-south, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

For a new app using Django 1.6, I am trying to create a `run.sh` that will run the initial commands on Bluemix.

I found an answer [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/165725/unable-to-deploy-a-python-django-application.html) that gives a run.sh file for the in-built migration that is supported in Django 1.7+

```
#!/bin/bash

 if [ -z "$VCAP_APP_PORT" ];
 then SERVER_PORT=80;
 else SERVER_PORT="$VCAP_APP_PORT";
 fi

 echo [$0] port is------------------- $SERVER_PORT

 python manage.py makemigrations
 python manage.py migrate

 echo "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser(username='username',password='password',email='you@example.com')" | python manage.py shell

 echo [$0] Starting Django Server...
 python manage.py runserver --noreload 0.0.0.0:$SERVER_PORT
```

Is there an idempotent way to run the equivalent commands (`schemamigration --auto`, `migrate`) in South?

Comment: What do you mean run the commands in South?

Comment: Check out the sample app https://github.com/fe01134/djangobluemix.

Comment: I mean the South equivalents of makemigrations, migrate etc. The sample app you linked to just does a syncdb, and I have created an issue there https://github.com/fe01134/djangobluemix/issues/1 suggesting adding the above code for Django 1.7+ however I am using Django 1.6

Comment: What do you mean the south equivalents?

Comment: Do you mean this, http://south.readthedocs.org/?

Comment: First-time using South here. My understanding is that South would need `schemamigration appname --initial` once, and `schemamigration appname --auto` and then `migrate appname` in the run.sh

Comment: I would strongly advice against creating your migrations on production. You should create them in your local development environment, and test them before you commit them along with the corresponding changes in your codebase.

Comment: Thank @knbk; Currently using Sqlite locally. However if I run migrations on a local Postgres DB, how do I replicate the migrations on Bluemix? (only way I know is the above run.sh)

Comment: The migrations are written in python files in a `<app>/migrations/` folder. You should commit these files to your repository and push them to Bluemix (or otherwise copy them). So `manage.py schemamigration` should only be run in development and committed/pushed, and `manage.py migrate` can then safely be run wherever you deploy your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly advice against creating your migrations on production. You should create them in your local development environment, and test them before you commit them along with the corresponding changes in your codebase.

The migrations are written in python files in a /migrations/ folder. You should commit these files to your repository and push them to Bluemix (or otherwise copy them). So manage.py schemamigration should only be run in development and committed/pushed, and manage.py migrate can then safely be run wherever you deploy your project.

Comment: Is it okay for you to use the comment by @knbk like this? This is the right answer, as I understand. Just not sure what the protocol is on accepting an answer by you which is essentially just someone else's comment.